# Is it possible to embed a clickable url into certain part of a image?

Tags: php, html

For example i have a jpeg image of a man standing on a table. I want to insert a clickable url to his shirt and also the table which he is standing. Is it possible to do?

Comment: i think your looking for the <area> Tag

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `<map>`

Image Map is a way that allow you to define certain area to be linked within a single image on a web page. This means that, rather than having to link the whole image as one link, you can have lots of different links within that one image.

You will get good tutorial [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/)

Answer (score 0):

It's in fact possible. You have to use `<map>` tag. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). There are a lot of tools online that allow you to create this image map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific way to 'mask' specific objects. But the closest that comes to mind is an imagemap (). In an imagemap you can define specific areas (rectangles) to link to certain pages.